# How to access and use custom class in the form of arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I am trying to create a custom class Student, which contains 2 fields, Name and Marks.
I read on the internet that I need Getters & Setters to do so.
So, I wrote the following code but it is giving me a NullPointerException.

```
import java.util.*;

class Student
{
    public String name;
    public int marks;
    public int getMarks()
    {
        return this.marks;
    }
    public void setMarks(int marks)
    {
        this.marks = marks;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
public class getterSetter
{
    public static void main(String[] ab)
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = s.nextInt();
        int x;
        Student[] student = new Student[n];
        String[] inputs = new String[n];
        s.nextLine();
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            String xx = s.nextLine();
            inputs[i] = xx;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            String[] words = inputs[i].split("\\s+");
            student[i].setName(words[0]);
            student[i].setMarks(Integer.parseInt(words[1]) + Integer.parseInt(words[2]) + Integer.parseInt(words[3]));
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(student[i].getName());
            System.out.println(student[i].getMarks());
        }
    }
}
```

The console screen is :

```
java getterSetter
3
abc 10 10 10
def 10 10 10
ghi 10 10 10
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at getterSetter.main(getterSetter.java:58)
```

Comment: You're not actually creating your `Student` objects. Before calling `student[i].setName(words[0]);`, you need to call `student[i] = new Student();`.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen thanks, that did the trick.. thanks